# Why can't show the keyCode in console.log?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I want to show all keyCodes when you type some characters in the input tag.
ob is the input ,bind a function `checkWord` with event `onkeydown`, why `console.log` can't show its keycode value?

```js
ob = window.document.getElementById("check");
function checkWord(){
    console.log(onkeydown.keyCode);
}
ob.addEventListener("onkeydown",checkWord);
```

```html
 
<input id="check" type="text">
```

I want `console.log` to show `65`  when I type `a` in the input tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues

- The event is named `keydown`.
- `keyCode` is a property of the `event` that get's passed to your handler

```js
ob = window.document.getElementById("check");
function checkWord(e){
    console.log(e.keyCode);
}
ob.addEventListener("keydown",checkWord);
```

```html
<input id="check" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm you can do it like that:

```js
// Getting Element
const textInput = document.getElementById("textInput");
// Adding event listener
textInput.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
  console.log(event.keyCode);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textInput">
```

In your code it would look like this:

```js
const ob = document.getElementById("check");
ob.addEventListener("keydown",checkWord);  
function checkWord(event){
  console.log(event.keyCode);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="check">
```

This mainly did not work because you did use the wrong event name (`onkeydown` -> `keydown`) and you didn't pass the event to your function.

BTW: `onkeydown` exists but is used like that:

```
object.onkeydown = function;
```

The difference between `onkeydown` and `addEventLisener` is that `onkeydown` is being defined once and with the event listeners you can add as meany to the same event as you want.

```
// Adds listener
object.onkeydown = function0;
// Overwrites the old listener
object.onkeydown = function1;

// Add listener
object.addEventLisener("keydown", function0);
// Add another listener to the stack
object.addEventLisener("keydown", function1);
```